# PHP file suddenly stopped working, shows blank page

Tags: php, json, mysqli

It was working fine just a while ago I was getting JSON response,  which was an array of JSON objects now it shows a blank page ,I have no idea why! Can anyone identify what's the problem here?
  here is the php code:

```
<?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="tourist"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");


if($con){
    mysqli_set_charset($con ,'utf8');
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM places";
    $query=mysqli_query($con ,$qry);       
    if (!$query) {
         $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
         $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $qry;
         die($message);
    }

    $return_arr = array();
    $row_array = array();

    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            $row_array['place_id'] = $r['place_id'];
            $row_array['place_name'] = $r['place_name'];
            //echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
            //$row_array['image'] =  "http://localhost/tourist/". $r['db_image'];  //.'" alt=\"\" /"';

            $row_array['image'] = "tourist/".$r['db_image'];
            $row_array['des'] = $r['description'];

            header('Content-Type: application/json');

            array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
        }
        return json_encode($return_arr);
    } else { 
        $return_arr['place_name'] = 'ERRO - Place inexistente'; 
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
    return json_encode($return_arr);

    mysqli_close($con);
} else { 
    $return_arr['place_name'] = 'ERRO - failure';
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
    return json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please format the code to eliminate scrolling.

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect($host ... Without ""

Comment: @Jonasw that won't solve anything though

Comment: A blank page usually means there's an error (and, thus, no meaningful output).  Check the logs PHP, turn on error reporting, etc.

Comment: you know what they say about a blank page(?) ^ that

Comment: This `mysql_error()` doesn't work with MySQLi_, so you will never know if there was a query error, should there be one.

Comment: This is not a function and therefore it does not need either of the  `return json_encode($return_arr);` These will terminate the script.

Comment: The `return json_encode($return_arr);` after the WHILE loop will be killing the script before it gets to echo the json. ___Suddenly stoppped working my left watsit, you broke it___ Then again we know that from the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few error in here

First you are mixing database access API's you cannot use `mysql_` and `mysqli_` calls. as you are connecting with `mysqli_` stick with that

Secondly you do not use a `return` unless you are in a function. Used as you have it is killing the script the first one it comes across in the normal flow of the code, and of course NOT sending the data back to your browser.

```
<?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="tourist"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("cannot connect");


if($con){
    mysqli_set_charset($con ,'utf8');
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM places";
    $query=mysqli_query($con ,$qry);       
    if (!$query) {

        //$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";

        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $qry;
        die($message);
    }

    $return_arr = array();
    $row_array = array();

    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            $row_array['place_id'] = $r['place_id'];
            $row_array['place_name'] = $r['place_name'];
            //echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
            //$row_array['image'] =  "http://localhost/tourist/". $r['db_image'];  //.'" alt=\"\" /"';

            $row_array['image'] = "tourist/".$r['db_image'];
            $row_array['des'] = $r['description'];

            header('Content-Type: application/json');

            array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
        }

        // This will be terminating the script
        //return json_encode($return_arr);

    } else { 
        $return_arr['place_name'] = 'ERRO - Place inexistente'; 
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

    // not needed
    //return json_encode($return_arr);

    mysqli_close($con);
} else { 
    $return_arr['place_name'] = 'ERRO - failure';
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

    // Not needed
    //return json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```